# Trying to parse JSON from API request with python

Tags: python, json, parsing

This is my code

```
import requests
import json
api_get = requests.get('https://api.domainsdb.info/v1/domains/search?domain=dou.ua')
        api_answer = api_get.json()
        print(api_answer)
```

This is answer

```
{'domains': [{'domain': 'dou.ua', 'create_date': None, 'update_date': '2019-01-08T12:41:02.907006', 'country': 'GB', 'isDead': 'False', 'A': ['178.79.140.30'], 'NS': ['ns3.linode.com', 'ns1.linode.com', 'ns2.linode.com', 'ns5.linode.com', 'ns4.linode.com'], 'CNAME': None, 'MX': [{'exchange': 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com', 'priority': 1}, {'exchange': 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com', 'priority': 1}, {'exchange': 'aspmx.l.google.com', 'priority': 0}], 'TXT': ['v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all']}], 'total': 1, 'time': '771', 'next_page': None}
```

Now i need take value of 'country'
When i do

```
import requests
import json
api_get = requests.get('https://api.domainsdb.info/v1/domains/search?domain=dou.ua')
api_answer = api_get.json()
country = json.loads(api_answer)
print(country["domains"]["country"])
```

I got error

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
```

When I do

```
import requests
import json
api_get = requests.get('https://api.domainsdb.info/v1/domains/search?domain=dou.ua')
api_answer = api_get.json()
country = json.dumps(api_answer)
print(country["domains"]["country"])
```

I got error

```
  print(country["domains"]["country"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I can't understand what I have to do.

Comment: `country["domains"]` is a `list`

Comment: I think you only want the value "country" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use  json.dumps the value returned is a string that is formed by dumping the json. You can not index a string by the keys, Instead you should index the json ie `api_answer` in your case.

```
import requests
import json
api_get = requests.get('https://api.domainsdb.info/v1/domains/search?domain=dou.ua')
api_answer = api_get.json()    
print(api_answer['domains'][0]['country'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
import requests
import json
api_get = requests.get('https://api.domainsdb.info/v1/domains/search?domain=dou.ua')
api_answer = api_get.json()
print(api_answer['domains'][0]['domain'])
```